# 500 Internal server Error on IIS 7.5 with PHP

Tags: php, iis, iis-7, phpmyadmin, iis-7.5

I'm running IIS7.5 on Windows 7. I have website under PHP but first it was on linux hosting and now i am running it on IIS. it successfully runs php on linux hosting but but on IIS it is showing error.

```
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server
Error An unknown FastCGI error occured

Module FastCgiModule
Notification ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler PHP_via_FastCGI
Error Code  0x00000000
Requested URL http://localhost:80/shubhshadi/index.php
Physical Path C:\inetpub\wwwroot\shubhshadi\index.php
Logon Method Anonymous
Logon User Anonymous
```

Comment: check this URL http://www.w3resource.com/php/installation/install-php-on-iis-in-windows-7.php

Comment: i have done this but it is not working.

Comment: I'd recommend not using the FastCGI and instead use mod_php.